# The device does not recognize the Telegram application

Tags: android, kotlin, android-package-managers, android-11

I use the standard function to determine if the application is installed:

```
private fun isTelegramAvailable(): Boolean {
    val pm = applicationContext.packageManager
    return try {
        pm.getPackageInfo("org.telegram.messenger", PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES)
        true
    } catch (e: PackageManager.NameNotFoundException) {
        false
    }
}
```

And everything worked fine for a long time, until a user appeared with a Samsung s20 ultra (Android 11) phone. This function has stopped working correctly, the application does not see the presence of Telegram on the device.

Has anyone come across a similar one? Maybe this phone model has some kind of restrictive settings that can be controlled? I will be grateful for any help!

Comment: Did you add [package visibility rules to your manifest](https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility)?

Comment: The page linking there is being called "behavioral changes": https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/package-visibility

Comment: @CommonsWare something happened again. With the added <queries> the application cannot see the Telegram

Comment: @MartinZeitler something happened again. With the added <queries> the application cannot see the Telegram

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @CommonsWare and @MartinZeitler !

Following article [package-visibility](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/package-visibility), I added the following code to the application manifest

```
<queries>
    <package android:name="org.telegram.messenger" />
    <package android:name="org.thunderdog.challegram" />
</queries>
```

(The second one for TelegramX)